# Order cols in two different rows with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to order cols that is placed in two different rows with Flexbox CSS, but I can only do it for one row. I need to have a mixed order between the two rows.

Right now I have to order and show the cols in row1 and the order and show the cols in row2, but I want to mix them and order them. (The order is OK in desktop view but I need this for mobile view. That's why I need a complete reorder from two rows).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mobile-order">
        <div class="col-md-4 box6">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box5">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box4">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mobile-order">
        <div class="col-md-4 box1">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box2">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box3">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.mobile-order {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;  
}
.test1 {
    order: 1;
}
.test2 {
    order: 2;
    background: #ccc;
}
.box1 {
    order: 1;
}
.box2 {
    order: 3;
}
.box3 {
    order: 5;
}
.box4 {
    order: 6;
}
.box5 {
    order: 4;
}
.box6 {
    order: 2;
}
```

[Bootply test page](http://www.bootply.com/p50qqYkhl9#)

This is how I need it for desktop and mobile:

**Desktop:**

```
Row1<br><div class="col-md-4 box6">1</div>  |   <div class="col-md-4 box5">2</div>   |   <div class="col-md-4 box4">3</div><br><br>

Row2<br>
<div class="col-md-4 box1">4</div>    |   <div class="col-md-4 box2">5</div>   |   <div class="col-md-4 box3">6</div>
```

**Mobile:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 box1">4</div><br>
<div class="col-md-4 box6">1</div><br>
<div class="col-md-4 box2">5</div><br>
<div class="col-md-4 box5">2</div><br>
<div class="col-md-4 box3">6</div><br>
<div class="col-md-4 box4">3</div>
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question please.

Comment: You can't mix the order of elements that do not share a parent...so it's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: It sounds like you should use media queries for this.

Comment: That is what i want to do @Paulie_D. I know i can´t but i thought someone could come up with some tricky solution anyway.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the two layouts should look like...the desktop and mobile views. Can you provide that?

Comment: I use media query to show the order Css aleady. I just need to be able to sort and mix between the two parents.

Comment: I added some info in the end of my question @Paulie_D

Comment: Is there some reason you have to use 2 rows?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS Display Module Level 3 introduces [`display: contents`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents):

> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and
>   pseudo-elements still generate boxes as normal. For the purposes of
>   box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had
>   been replaced with its children and pseudo-elements in the document
>   tree.

You can use it to "ignore" the rows and display the inner flex items as if they belonged the same flex container. Then you are able to mix them as you want.

```css
.mobile-order {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  display: contents;
}
.test2 > div {
  background: #ccc;
}
.box1 { order: 1; }
.box2 { order: 2; }
.box3 { order: 3; }
.box4 { order: 4; }
.box5 { order: 5; }
.box6 { order: 6; }
```

```html
<div class="container mobile-order">
  <div class="row test2 mobile-order">
    <div class="col-md-4 box1">1 (row 1)</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 box5">5 (row 1)</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 box2">2 (row 1)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row test1 mobile-order">
    <div class="col-md-4 box3">3 (row 2)</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 box6">6 (row 2)</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 box4">4 (row 2)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's not widely supported yet, though.

Comment: Thanks but where can i find out supported browsers for this? @Oriol

Comment: @user2986959 According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility), currently it's only supported by Firefox 37+

Comment: Ok so this is the only option if i dont want to add Jquery then?

Comment: Well, I guess you could also place the elements at the desired places with absolute positioning. But the layout won't be flexible at all.

Comment: Upvoted for introducing me to a new CSS feature. I love that I'm still learning new things after all these years :)

Comment: I like this solution but there need to be support for more browsers. I guess i have to add some Jquery if anyone else knows some other magic trick =)

Answer (score 0):

If using a single *row* is an option, basic flexbox with wrapping will take care of this with a media query.

```css
[class*="box"] {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.mobile-order {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .mobile-order {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .test1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .test2 {
    order: 2;
    background: #ccc;
  }
  .box1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .box2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .box3 {
    order: 5;
  }
  .box4 {
    order: 6;
  }
  .box5 {
    order: 4;
  }
  .box6 {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mobile-order">
    <div class="col-md-4 box6">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 box5">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 box4">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 box1">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 box2">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 box3">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen.io Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yYpXmO?editors=110)

Comment: Yes thanks @Paulie_D. That was my original plan but in my Episerver solution i need to use two rows. Thats why i have this problem.